# python program without stackless.run()

Tags: python, python-stackless

How the below program execute my member `A.fun` without calling `stackless.run()` in the program?

```
import stackless

class A:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.ch = stackless.channel()
        stackless.tasklet(self.fun)()

    def __call__(self,val):
        self.ch.send(val)

    def fun(self):
       while 1:
         v = self.ch.receive()
         print "hi" , v


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = A("sh")
    obj(6)
```

output:

```
hi 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used stackless, but I'm guessing from the documentation that calling [channel.send](http://stackless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/stackless/channels.html#channel.send) makes the scheduler call the other tasklet.